# Select date which is bigger than another date on a second afinity

Tags: sql, database, datetime

I have two identical tables in 2 different DBs ( one local and one remote ). Both of them have a `Datetime` ( or `Datetime2` or anything else, I can still change that ) column which specifies when they were added. What I want is to get the records from the remote table to the local table that have not already been brought.

For this a get the max value from the local table, then I tried to put the condition `WHERE remoteTable.CreateTime > maxLocalValue`, but I don't know why this seems to overwrite some records on the boundry. Any better way to do this ? On a second or minute level ?

Comment: How do you know that they are *on the boundary*? What is ypur precision?

Comment: Are both systems in the same time zone?

Comment: Maybe try to convert the dates to "seconds from 1950" and compare them that way.

Comment: I used `DATEDIFF` function. That seems to let you use any affinity you want. Should I delete the question or post the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

since we know which values have been added already to the local table, only add the values from the remote table that are not in the local table. Let local_table repersents the local table and remote_table repersents remote table and that rcd_1 is a column in both tables that repersents the DATE type.

```
INSERT INTO local_table (col_1,.....(how evermany columns you need), rcd_1)
SELECT rcd_1 FROM remote_table 
where remote_table.rcd_1 <> local_table.rcd_1;
```

the way you explained you question would suggest that only newer dates are added to local from remote so as long as this hold true you should get the desired results.